# "Queue metrics not available” for Logstash pipeline monitoring

Tags: logstash, monitoring, elastic-stack

I want to work on monitoring queue metrics from logstash in elasticsearch monitoring.

After enabling monitoring from logstash node this is all I see in the pipeline monitoring section.

[image]

Even the official documentation has the similar screenshot that says “Queue metrics not available” for Logstash pipeline monitoring. Is it still in beta? I was expecting some stats related to the persistent queues.

Using : ES-Stack Version 7.16.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a feature that has not been implemented yet as of Jan 2022. Here's the code

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/main/x-pack/plugins/monitoring/public/components/logstash/pipeline_viewer/views/queue.js

Here's a github issue open since 2019 and it doesnt look like this feature is going to see the light of the day anytime soon

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/10480